# Unity 2D Knockback, Player Not being effected, Code not being called

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics, game-development

(New to Stackoverflow btw) So I've currently working on a 2D top-down Zelda like game and I've made a reusable knockback script that can be assigned to enemies. I have received no errors in the console, but when the Player collides with Enemy nothing happens Player still receives damage but there is no knockback or response from the Debug.Log

Following Code for Knockback:

```
public class Knockback_Script : MonoBehaviour
{

    //balls
    public float Power;
    
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        //Make a custom tag OR LAYER where the player gets affected by all
        //or just make another "OnTiggerEnter2D"
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            Rigidbody2D Player = other.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();

            Vector2 difference = Player.transform.position - transform.position;
            difference = difference * Power;
            Player.AddForce(difference, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            Debug.Log("WORKS");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Pos the code you use for applying damage on collision. If that works but this doesn’t, there must be some difference and it might be visible in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Change Collider2D to Collision2D.

OnCollisionEnter2D() need Collision2D.
OnTriggerEnter2D() need Collider2D.